# Bootstrap(HTML) , show the listbox on the bottom of the Div

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage which uses bootstrap. In that page I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 ">
                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" CssClass="control-label  " Font-Bold="true" AssociatedControlID="ddlCOS"
                    Text="Not Combinable with:"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" 
                <asp:ListBox ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control "  SelectionMode="Multiple" ></asp:ListBox>
                           </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row" 
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 RWCL"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                *Hold down Ctrl Key to select multiple choices.
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I want to do is to show message ***Hold down Ctrl Key to select multiple choices.** exactly under the listbox. It goes under the listbox but there is some space between them . See picture:
[image]

I did all I knew to get rid of that space but  the problem is listbox aligns top vertical on the div

I tried Vertical-align bottom , Margin bottom 0 and padding bottom 0 but none of these works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the text to the listbox:

```
 <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 ">
        <asp:Label ID = "Label15" runat="server" CssClass="control-label  " Font-Bold="true" AssociatedControlID="ddlCOS"
            Text="Not Combinable with:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <asp:ListBox ID = "DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control "  SelectionMode="Multiple" ></asp:ListBox>
        <p class="help-block">*Hold down Ctrl Key to select multiple choices.</p>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Added class="help-block" (a bootstrap class for input helps)

Comment: Maybe this is the only simple choice. Since for some reason it is deigned so that all controls stick to the top of the rows.

Comment: I think "<span class="help-block">*Hold down Ctrl Key to select multiple choices.</span>" will help you.